# How to resize UIViewControllerWrapperView

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, hide

I'm trying to display an UIImageView within a tab on an iPad. I hide the tab bar and I want the UIImageView to take up the entire screen, ie be full screen. I try resizing everything in sight and the image will not occupy the space used by the tab bar.
I've tried debugging, printing the frame for each view going up the view hierarchy. Everything looks ok until it gets up to UIViewControllerWrapperView which has the smaller size.

What is UIViewControllerWrapperView and how do I resize it?

Answer (score -1):

have you tried reseting the frame on the UIImageView

```
[imageView setFrame:theController.view.bounds];
```

Comment: Yes I have. When I said I've resized everything, means I've resized the image view and controller view. I wrote a debug routine to bring the frame for each view going up the hierarchy.
Going up, the ImageView, Scroll View and View look properly sized. However, the superview of the View is the UIViewControllerWrapperView which is not resizing.

My current theory is that it cannot be done within a UITabbar. I've found an example where someone setup a UITabBar delegate and when the desired tab is selected, they updated the view for the whole window to swap out the tab bar controller.